# Trying to display and transform 3 xml files through an XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am trying to get some of the elements of 3 different XML files to display in the same table through XSLT. I have three XML records and an XSD schema. I need to transform all three XML documents through an XSLT file to:

Create XSLT to display all of my records. I should only display the following fields: creators’ name, forename, title, format, publication date.

Then I need to order the display by publication date, oldest first and display all the creators alphabetized by last name (it has to do this even if there are not multiple creators.

I have been able to create my XML files but honestly, but I have no idea where to go with my XSLT file and I hope someone mind be willing to reduce the number of tears I have to shed. Thanks.

The XSD schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="catalog">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Schema mimics bibliographic elements of MODS in a simpler form</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="catalogRecord" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="titleInfo">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="subtitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<!--titleInfo -->
<xs:element name="nameInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<!-- use the "name" field for the surname or only-name like Prince -->
```

```
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="forename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="role">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="author"/>
<xs:enumeration value="editor"/>
<xs:enumeration value="performer"/>
<xs:enumeration value="director"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="primary" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<!--nameInfo -->
<xs:element name="originInfo">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="place" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="publisher" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="dateIssued" type="xs:gYear"/>
<xs:element name="edition" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<!--originInfo -->
<xs:element name="typeOfResource">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="book"/>
<xs:enumeration value="sound recording"/>
<xs:enumeration value="film"/>
<xs:enumeration value="score"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<!--typeOfResource -->
<xs:element name="subject" type="xs:string" minOccurs="2"     maxOccurs="unbounded">
<!--you may use free-text tags or LCSH subjects -->
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<catalog xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalogschema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<catalogRecord>
<titleInfo>
<title>The Selfish Gene</title>
<subtitle></subtitle>
</titleInfo>
<nameInfo primary="false">
<name>Dawkins</name>
<forename>Richard</forename>
<role>author</role>
</nameInfo>
<originInfo>
<place>Oxford, England</place>
<publisher>Oxford University Press</publisher>
<dateIssued>2006</dateIssued>
<edition>3</edition>
</originInfo>
<typeOfResource>book</typeOfResource>
<subject>Biology</subject>
<subject>Evolution</subject>
<subject>Genetics</subject>
<subject>Acedemic Publishing</subject>
</catalogRecord>
</catalog>


<catalog xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalogschema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<catalogRecord>
<titleInfo>
<title>The Heart of Saturday Night</title>
<subtitle></subtitle>
</titleInfo>
<nameInfo primary="false">
<name>Waits</name>
<forename>Tom</forename>
<role>performer</role>
</nameInfo>
<nameInfo primary="false">
<name>Howe</name>
<forename>Bones</forename>
<role>director</role>
</nameInfo>
<originInfo>
<place>Los Angelos, CA</place>
<publisher>Asylum Records</publisher>
<dateIssued>1974</dateIssued>
<edition>1</edition>
</originInfo>
<typeOfResource>sound recording</typeOfResource>
<subject>Jack Kerouac</subject>
<subject>Southern California</subject>
<subject>Love</subject>
</catalogRecord>
</catalog>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<catalog xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalogschema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<catalogRecord>
<titleInfo>
<title>Fences</title>
<subtitle></subtitle>
</titleInfo>
<nameInfo primary="false">
<name>August</name>
<forename>Wilson</forename>
<role>Author</role>
</nameInfo>
<nameInfo primary="false">
<name>Denzel Washington</name>
<role>Director</role>
</nameInfo>
<nameInfo primary="false">
<name>Viola Davis</name>
<role>Performer</role>
</nameInfo>
<originInfo>
<place>Hollywood, CA</place>
<publisher>Paramount Pictures</publisher>
<dateIssued>2016</dateIssued>
<edition></edition>
</originInfo>
<typeOfResource>film</typeOfResource>
<subject>African American families</subject>
<subject>Family</subject>
<subject>Pittsburg, PA</subject>
<subject>1950's</subject>
<subject>American history</subject>
</catalogRecord>
</catalog>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: You could start by reading a book like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm.

Comment: "I've bought a car and I'm sitting in the driver's seat but I have no idea how to start the engine." The only advice we can give is: don't start the engine until you've learnt how to drive.

Comment: Do you have another book suggestion Martin? We were just assigned a few tutorials and some videos but no actual textbook and I couldn't get the one mentioned above to open. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to display specific xml elements from multiple xml files in one HTML table, right? I mean, I am pretty sure that is what I am trying to do, but I want to make sure I am trying to figure out the right thing.